# Zoo max of varying interval length

Tags: r, zoo, moving-average

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to create a dynamic function in R that stores the max value of a vector with a repeating interval. Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
library(zoo)

x <- rep(1:3, times = 10)
width <- rep(1:3, times = 10)

test <- rollapply(x , width, FUN = max, partial = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(x, test)
```

Since width is a repeating interval 1:3 and so is x 1:3. I my result (test) to return values (1:3) but as you can see in df it does not. Thanks

Comment: To be more clear: Test is return values of 1,3,3 and I expect values of 1,2,3.  Because that is the max value at each interval

Comment: `align="right"` maybe?

Comment: Great. That does the trick.

Comment: or `rollapplyr` which defaults to `align="right"`.